# How to create drill through using a measure?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I want to Drill through title measure where fields are displayed through which drill has been done.

How can I do that with a measure?? Whichever field I drill through should be displayed in another page with its details.

Comment: Does your measure return a numerical value?

Comment: @AmilaMGunawardana Measure should return name of drilled through fields

Comment: If you can explain with an example its easier to give answer

Comment: @AmilaMGunawardana Suppose I drilled through a field in a visual, then it should be displayed in title on a new page which field I have drilled through.

Comment: All the categories are in one table, right?

Comment: @AmilaMGunawardana Yes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `SELECTEDVALUE(<Column name>)` [function](https://dax.guide/selectedvalue/) for displaying the filtered values on the visual in the drilled page.